# Find all Independent edge sets in a graph

Tags: graphs-and-networks

The function returns only one answer. But most graphs have more than one possible independent edge set.

```
g = Graph[{1 <-> 2, 2 <-> 3, 3 <-> 4, 4 <-> 5, 1 <-> 5}]
FindIndependentEdgeSet[g]
```

Mathematica returns  `{1 <-> 2, 3 <-> 4}`. we know that {1,5} {3,4} is an answer too.

How do we list all possible answers?

Answer (score 5):

Could could find independent vertex sets of the [line graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_graph).

```
g = Graph[{1 <-> 2, 2 <-> 3, 3 <-> 4, 4 <-> 5, 1 <-> 5}, VertexLabels -> "Name"]
```

[image]

```
lg = LineGraph[g, 
  VertexLabels -> Thread[Range@EdgeCount[g] -> EdgeList[g]]]
```

[image]

```
es = FindIndependentVertexSet[lg, Infinity, All]
(* {{3, 5}, {2, 5}, {2, 4}, {1, 4}, {1, 3}} *)

HighlightGraph[g, EdgeList[g][[#]], 
   GraphHighlightStyle -> "Thick"] & /@ es
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

```
Select[Subsets[EdgeList[g], {2, EdgeCount[g]}], 
 IndependentEdgeSetQ[g, #] &]
```

> {{1 <-> 2, 3 <-> 4}, {1 <-> 2, 4 <-> 5}, {2 <-> 3, 4 <-> 5}, {2 <-> 3,
>      1 <-> 5}, {3 <-> 4, 1 <-> 5}}

```
HighlightGraph[g, #] & /@ %
```

[image]

Note I cut the subset length off at 2, obviously every individual edge is technically/trivially an independent edge set as well (at least according to `IndependentEdgeSetQ` )

Comment: very good solution!